# How can a string array be databound to a ListBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I'm relatively new to .NET GUI programming using WinForms (the project I'm working on is targetting .NET 2.0 for deployment reasons), and I'm trying to bind a ListBox in a Form to a string[] property that is defined in the form:

```
namespace AVPriorityUI
{
    public partial class AVPriorityUI : Form
    {
        public AVPriorityUI()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string[] ProcessNames
        {
            get { ... }
            set { ... }
        }
    }
}
```

No matter what I do, I can't get Visual Studio 2008 to offer up the ProcessNames property as a valid source to bind to.  What do I need to do differently to make this work?

[EDIT] I've been trying to use the GUI to establish the binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to set the list box's DataSource to the ProcessNames property in the code itself. If you are trying to use the UI to set the DataSources/Bindings that may be the culprit.

ie:

```
mylistBox.DataSource = this.ProcessNames;
```

Comment: That was it... I've never seen a UI that works for the complex case but fails utterly at the trivial... :(

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288424(VS.71).aspx

listbox.Items.AddRange(this.ProcessNames);

Comment: scratch my solution... old c# syntax.... no longer valid in 2.0 and higher it seems....

Answer (score 0):

this works for me in a simple test just now:

```
string[] alist = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h" };
listBox1.DataSource = alist;
```

Comment: How do you make this work if alist is a globally scoped variable and you add more elements after databinding?